# Magento tree category error in Admin

Tags: php, admin, magento-1.8

I am using the promotions price rules and when i try to add a category to the selection via the dropdown category list i get the following error. i am using magento 1.8.  Does anyone know why $this->getRoot() may be returning NULL?  Thank you

```
tree = new Ext.tree.TreePanel.Enhanced('tree-div_1413303550', {
    animate:          false,
    loader:           categoryLoader,
    enableDD:         false,
    containerScroll:  true,
    selModel:         new Ext.tree.CheckNodeMultiSelectionModel(),
    rootVisible:      '
Fatal error: Call to a member function getIsVisible() on a non-object in xxx\app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\category\checkboxes\tree.phtml on line 171
```